# 404 error on page when I change default controller to new controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had created login page in codeigniter  and made it default controller when the application is hit but I am getting  404 page not found error when the application is hit. Please find below code of controller as main.php config and route file changes placed. My controller name is main.php and the code is as follows

```
<?php  
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

class Main extends CI_Controller {  
    //functions  
    function login()  
    {  
        $data['title'] = 'CodeIgniter Simple Login Form With Sessions';  
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->load->view("login", $data);  
    }
```

htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>

<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

route file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
```

config file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['encryption_key'] = 'xRUqKhsoZ5qV6y3kqARFJFdPqJvp7X2z';
```

Comment: maybe it's `$route['default_controller'] = 'main/login';` ?

Comment: as per your comment i modified  i am able see my view page. in view page  after filling information and do a submit  my page action is on controllers(main) one of the methods(login_validation()) is showing  http 404 the web page cannotbe found

Answer (score 0):

You need to set baseurl in config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/cifolder/';
```

Then change default controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
```

Comment: still i am getting  404 error  after setting as per you said

Comment: @Vamsi whats the name of your main folder

Comment: @Vamsi please check i have updated my code it is  not working because your class name is Main and you set it as main so it will not work.if still not solved let me know

Comment: my controller name is main.php and my class name is Main and one more what do you mean by cifolder  i had set as $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';

Comment: @Vamsi First of all class name and file name should be same So Change File name to Main.php .cifolder is the root folder of codeigniter when you extract zip file in that folder all other folders are located like cifolder\application\view . if still not solved let me know

Comment: hi my class name and controller name i had given as Main now and updated in default controller as Main and config file i had given as http://localhost/application/ am i correct . i was new to this codeigniter  wamp64

Comment: @Vamsi no brother you have to give root folder name which means you have to give that folder name in which application folder is located

Comment: https://prnt.sc/mw7yg9  This is url of directory structure in that CodeIgniter-3.0.1 is root folder same way you have to give your folder name

Comment: still the issue exist after modification

Comment: @Vamsi whats tha name of your root folder ?? and share the config file code and routes file code

Comment: wamp64\www\apllication\controllers path formy applicaion

Comment: there must be a another folder after www/rootfoldername/application @Vamsi

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

Comment: router is  */
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: no i dont have....i only have what i mentioned earlier and  one more is that    if  i make other controller  as default i am getting but i dont understand  y this is showing 404 for Main.php controller

Comment: if rootfolder is not there then create one folder is not there then create a folder called  CI and then add all codeigniter folders and files into it like application,system,assets,uploads and all other files and then use my updated code

Comment: have you put your login file in view folder or not and please check the name it is case sensitive